# DART - Cannot compile the code in build.gradle file

Tags: flutter, dart

```
   android {
         ...

   }

    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Its between the android {... } where im missing a line of code and hence not able to compile. What am i missing? im not able to export it in release mode.

Comment: can you post the actual error

Comment: Remove the first closing bracket. All of the provided snippet goes inside the `android` block.